# iOS 8 - Localizing widget display name

Tags: ios, widget

I am making a widget for my app and I would like to localize the display name. I have set the property: `Application has localized display name = YES;` in my Info.plist already and i have made the localized:
 `Info.strings (Danish)` and `Info.strings (English)` each files containing the lines: "CFBundleDisplayName" = "MyDisplayName"; - one in english and one in danish
"CFBundleName" = "myName";

It still does not work! Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project build after those changes? Are you trying on a device or in the simulator?

Comment: Im testing it on a device. I have cleaned the build and tried, but still no luck sadly

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is probably already solved but I give you mine: You could have three things wrong:

1. You shouldn't put CFBundleDisplayName inside quotes in InfoPlist.strings. So instead of "CFBundleDisplayName" = "MyDisplayName"; use CFBundleDisplayName = "MyDisplayName";
2. The file is named InfoPlist.strings
3. I had this wrong in the beginning: I forgot to add the InfoPlist.strings into the project. So files were in the directory but they weren't added. Check that one also.